# Finding a test which maximises the power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-power

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $F$. If we have:

- null hypothesis: $H_0$: $F$ is standard normal, $N(0, 1)$
- alternative: $H_1$: $F$ is double exponential, with density $\frac{1}{4} e^{-|x|/2}$

How do I find the test of size $\alpha$, $\alpha < \frac{1}{4}$ which maximises the power? And how do I find the power?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and share your thoughts.

Comment: The null and alternative are simple hypotheses, so by the Neyman-Pearson lemma the likelihood ratio test is most powerful for any size.